# Getting a ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, alter

I have used the following code before to get what I wanted but then I added some Foreign Keys and it is messing it up:

```
DELETE FROM Faculty WHERE LastName LIKE 'Z%'

DELETE FROM Courses WHERE FirstYrOffered='1999'
```

Simply I am trying to delete an entry from the table but it is not working correctly. This is how my tables are looking:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacultyID int,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30),
EMail varchar(60),
BirthDate DATE,
Numbr_Courses int,
PRIMARY KEY (FacultyID)
);

CREATE TABLE Courses(
CourseID int,
CourseDisc varchar(4),
CourseNum varchar(4),
NumbrCred varchar(1),
FirstYrOffered int,
CourseTitle varchar(75),
PRIMARY KEY (CourseID)
);

CREATE TABLE Faculty_Courses(
InstanceID int,
FacultyID int,
CourseDisc varchar(4),
CourseID int,
CourseNum varchar(4),
CourseTitle varchar(75),
PRIMARY KEY (InstanceID),
FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES Courses(CourseID)
);
```

I have looked up the ALTER TABLE code examples but don't really understand what I am doing with that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: usage of FOREIGN KEY Constraints is to help keep this spread-out data consistent [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). May i ask why you want to delete it?

Comment: This is all for a class to show we understand how to do it. So basically I need to delete it because it is in the instructions. I am going to try the answer below with the delete cascade option to see if it works.

Comment: i had 2 option if it fail. Give it a try, if fail let me know

Comment: @Adi Prasetyo Yes the delete cascade option worked perfectly thanks for trying to help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to delete the corresponding records from Faculty_Courses, then delete the records from faculty and courses tables. Alternatively, set [on delete cascade option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) on the foreign keys.